# I have matrix A and matrix B. I want to get values of A depending on values in B

Tags: matlab

I have matrix

```
A=magic(4)*10
```

and matrix

```
B=[6 6 2 6;  1 1 2 1; 7 7 2 1; 3 3 -1 3 ]
```

I want to get values of `A` depending on values in `B`. For example:

```
A=
160 20  30  130
50  110 100 80
90  70  60  120
40  140 150 10

B=
6   6   2   6
6   6   2   2
2   6   2   6
6   2   -1  2
```

I want to start at `A(1,1)` (value=160). Then, If the corresponding value on `B`, `B(1,1) = 6`, I want to get the element that is on the right, `A(1,2)`, and  if `B(1,1) = 2`, I want to get value that is below, `A(2,1)`. Finally, if the value is -1, I do not want to proceed. In the end I want to get result like this:

```
result=
160
20
30
100
60
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow your explanation at all.

Comment: Why does "6" mean "right" and "2" means "below"? How do you determine the directions?

Comment: Also what do `7` and `3` mean ?

Comment: @PaulR B may just contain 6, 2 and -1. Let's see if NEPASH can confirm.

Comment: @Pavan: see above: `B=[6 6 2 6;  1 1 2 1; 7 7 2 1; 3 3 -1 3 ]`

Comment: @PaulR Sorry, I was looking at the second example, where it is 6, 2 and -1 only.

Comment: @Pavan: yes, I'm not sure why B changes between the first and second case...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
% Inizialize matices
A=magic(4)*10;
B=[6 6 2 6;  1 1 2 1; 7 7 2 1; 3 3 -1 3 ];

% Inizialize internal variables
contin=1;
row=1;
column=1;
result=[];

while contin==1
    %append value
    result=[result A(row, column)];
    if B(row, column)==6
        column=column+1; %go to the right
    elseif B(row, column)==2
        row=row+1; %go down
    elseif B(row, column)==-1
        contin=0; %break
        result(end)=[]; %delete last value 
    end
end

result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Digna. This was something I was trying to solve for a while. Thanks again :).

Comment: Guys B does contain other numbers as well and they mean other direction. I asked for only -1 and 6 and 2 in order to avoid writing longer elseif statements.

Comment: Just add more elseif before the elseif for -1 for those numbers and the corresponding directions. For example, if 9 means go up, put "row=row-1;", if 4 means go to the left, put "column=column-1". You may need to check that row and column do not take values below 1 too.